# Calling C++ method in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I need to call a c++ function from c#.

c++ function is

```
BOOL Usb_GetDevicesList(int &iNbDevices, char aszDeviceName[][128]);
```

I tried

```
  [DllImport("UsbComm.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int Usb_GetDevicesList(int iNbDevices, out byte[][] aszDeviceName);
```

I got error

> Cannot marshal 'parameter #2': There is no marshaling support for
>   nested arrays.

Please help me in converting this c++ function to C#.

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991383/call-a-c-function-from-c-sharp

Comment: Presumably `iNbDevices` contains the length of the supplied array `aszDeviceName` on entry, and the number of items written to the array on exit? With `FALSE` returned if the supplied array is not long enough. Unless you also explain the semantics of the function it is hard to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just flatten the 2D array to a single dimensional one and then pass it.

```
 flattened_array[(y * width) + x] = source[x][y];
```

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732208/a-safe-way-to-pass-an-array-or-arrys-in-c-sharp-to-a-dll)

Comment: You would need to change the C++ function as well to accept a flattened 2D array.

Comment: We cannot change in C++ function

Comment: Look into this in that case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705857/marshal-a-c-char-array-to-c-sharp

Comment: @AkashPradhan The C++ function doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: ^Yes I posted the link where no change in C++ is required.

Comment: @Akash Then what is the rest of your answer for?